# duplicated text sent by actionchains send_keys when integrating in for loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to send_keys to textarea so I use actionchains to send keys.
I used this code:

```
url='https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi'
browserdriver.get(url)
list_test=['product description 1','product description 2']
for i in range (0,2):   
    try:
        body_text=list_test[i]
        browserdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")      
        item = WebDriverWait(browserdriver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "textarea")))        
        actions.move_to_element(item).send_keys(body_text).perform()
        actions.reset_actions()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
print("done")
```

And the result of text was sent to Google Translate as below:

```
product description 1product description 1product description 2
```

You can see that is so weird that it should be like this:

```
product description 1product description 2
```

I also inserted print() to utils.py in source code of actionchains in order to know what typing text is sent to send_keys function:

```
def keys_to_typing(value):
    """Processes the values that will be typed in the element."""
    typing = []
    for val in value:
        if isinstance(val, Keys):
            typing.append(val)
        elif isinstance(val, int):
            val = str(val)
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
        else:
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])    
    print(typing)#this is a code line that I inserted
    return typing
```

and the output console of keys_to_typing is:

```
['p', 'r', 'o', 'd', 'u', 'c', 't', ' ', 'd', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', '1']
['p', 'r', 'o', 'd', 'u', 'c', 't', ' ', 'd', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', '1']

['p', 'r', 'o', 'd', 'u', 'c', 't', ' ', 'd', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', '2']
['p', 'r', 'o', 'd', 'u', 'c', 't', ' ', 'd', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', '2']
```

And this is the send_keys function in actionchains sourcecode:

```
def send_keys(self, keys_to_send):
        """
        Sends keys to current focused element.

        :Args:
         - keys_to_send: The keys to send.  Modifier keys constants can be found in the
           'Keys' class.
        """
        typing = keys_to_typing(keys_to_send)
        if self._driver.w3c:
            for key in typing:
                self.key_down(key)
                self.key_up(key)
        else:
            self._actions.append(lambda: self._driver.execute(
                Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ACTIVE_ELEMENT, {'value': typing}))
        return self
```

Pls help me to explain this weird situation?
I do not know why in loop for, actionchains.send_keys send duplicated content?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `reset_actions()` doesn't work as expected (adding `perform()` doesn't solve the problem). `self.key_down(key)` and `self.key_up(key)` in `send_keys()` stores the characters to type in `self.w3c_actions.key_action`

```
def key_down(self, value, element=None):
    if element:
        self.click(element)
    if self._driver.w3c:
        self.w3c_actions.key_action.key_down(value)
        self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pause()
    else:
        self._actions.append(lambda: self._driver.execute(
            Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ACTIVE_ELEMENT,
            {"value": keys_to_typing(value)}))
    return self
```

[image]

Those actions should be cleared when `reset_actions()` is called

```
def reset_actions(self):
    """
        Clears actions that are already stored locally and on the remote end
    """
    if self._driver.w3c:
        self.w3c_actions.clear_actions()
    self._actions = []
```

But they don't.

When `send_keys()` is called with **product description 2** the text is added to `key_action`, which already contains the actions for typing **product description 1** from the first `for` iteration, so it prints **product description 1product description 2**.

Possible solution is to create `ActionChains` instance inside the loop

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    try:
        body_text = list_test[i]
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "textarea")))
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(item).send_keys(body_text).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
```

**Update**

I opened an issue in [bugs.chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2993). The issue was reproduced, but won't be fixed (in the foreseeable future atleast).

Comment: what an absolutely clear guidance and explaination! thank you so much. Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: I can not believe this still did not get fixed. I came by this after spending an hour looking for a work around. Putting ActionChains into the instance itself was the solution for me!